# How to get orgin and normal for a plane, from PlaneWidget

Tags: python, vtk, plane

How to get orgin and normal, from plane widget, and give it to vktPlane? My code actually doesn't work.

```
planeWidget = vtk.vtkImagePlaneWidget()
planeWidget.SetInputData(reader.GetOutput())
planeWidget.SetSliceIndex(reader.GetOutput().GetDimensions()[2]/2)

clippingPlane=vtk.vtkPlane()
clippingPLane.SetOrigin(planeWidget.GetSelectedPlaneProperty())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vtkImagePlaneWidget::GetCenter()` and `vtkImagePlaneWidget::GetNormal()` should give you what you need.